# Mongoose .findOne Error returns the model found?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So I'm trying to access this account by using the findOne function in mongoose, and I'm trying to console.log the error, but the error is just the correct model found.. once I find the correct model I want to access one of the nested objects in the schema so I can edit the value.

I'm not sure why this is happening, below I put the code as well as the error that was logged into the console, I can provide more if needed.

```
    let accountSchema = mongoose.Schema({
       username:{
           type: String,
           required: true,
           index: true,
           unique: true,
       },
       password:{
           type: String,
           required: true,
       },
       money:{
           type: Number,

       },
       inventory: { type: [{
           weed: { type: Number },
           coke: { type: Number },
       }]},
  });


mp.events.addCommand('coke', (player) => {
    console.log(player.name);
    Account.findOne({username: 'a'}, function(acc, err) {
        if(err) return console.log(err);
        console.log(acc.username);
       acc.inventory[1] = acc.inventory[1] + 1;
       acc.save(function(err){
          if(err) return player.outputChatBox('Not logged in');
          player.outputChatBox('Added 1 coke');
       });
    });
});

(Console) {"_id":"5b6acbbbc285477e39514cb9","username":"a","password":"$2a$10$XABqooqFRINYVdJ79.i2E.5xdpitRrfZxUBmIPAZjjaXKvvLDc2y2","money":5000,"inventory":[{"_id":"5b6acbbbc285477e39514cbb","weed":0},{"_id":"5b6acbbbc285477e39514cba","coke":0}],"__v":0}
```

Comment: Added it to the top.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The callback function for the `.findOne` method has the following signature:

```
function (err, obj) {

}
```

You are using the arguments in the wrong order - the error object is the first argument and the object found is the second one.

Comment: Thanks for the help

Comment: It's a common mistake. It happened lots of time to me as well. That's why nowadays I use the Promise API.

Answer (score 3):

The **.findOne** method callback must have the following parameters `function (err, res)`. So you are setting them in a reversed order.

Check http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOne